# How to specify fixed length fields in the xml config file in jpos

Tags: iso8583, jpos, iso8583-1993

We can specify numbers up to 99 with length IFA_LLNUM, as well as strings up to 999 with LLLCHAR, but how can we specify a number with a fixed length of 8 or specify a string with a fixed length of 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR` for that.

Comment: how to specify a number with a fixed length